# Automatically Download Apple Wallet Pass After Redemption

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

Is it possible to download a second wallet pass automatically after redeeming a wallet pass. We have seen that this is possible but could not find any solution for this. As i know our api can only return one kind of pass to our servers with wether you **update** or **renewing** the pass. We have attached a video where you can see that they download a second pass automatically without adding the card. As far we know the Apple Api only returns a **get** when want to download a new pass with a push notification

In this video you can see that 
the wallet is downloading a next pass (5:39)

[WalletPass Video](https://vimeo.com/150761205)

Would really appreciate help in this

Regards,

Oktay

Comment: I don't see a new pass being added, just three updates to an existing pass - the first removes the barcode, the second adds a new barcode and changes the colour and the third removes the barcode once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product in the video is our product.  All changes are made by updating a pass already in the wallet.  As long as the `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber` remain the same, you can change any other content in a pass.

We have a redeem API endpoint that marks the first pass as being used, and sends an update to remove the barcode.  15 seconds later, a second update is automatically sent with the new pass details.  The new details replace the old details of the original pass. The user only ever has one pass in their wallet. It is not possible to push a second pass (with a different `passTypeIdentifier` and `serialNumber`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i really appreciate that.